# typescript: detect assignment to un-initialized variable at compile time

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please see the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20ITest%20%7B%0D%0A%09Name%3a%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20t%3aITest;%0D%0A//var%20t%3aITest%20=%20%7BName%3anull%7D;%0D%0A%0D%0At.Name%20=%20%22hello%22;)

```
interface ITest {
    Name: string
}

var t:ITest;
//var t:ITest = {Name:null};

t.Name = "hello";
```

this is a runtime error as t never initialized, and can solve by uncommenting the line. Is there a way to detect assignment to un-initialized variable at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a standardized way in TypeScript to prevent assignment to a property of an un-initialized variable.

Many would try to catch that error through a unit test or an assertion library that would verify the object exists before setting the property.

Answer (score 1):

No TS can't do that. For good reason. Say you declare in file a, setup in file b and use in file c.

TypeScript can't know that you are going to load file a then b then c. At runtime you might end up loading files c first (using a script tag) and will still get this error.

Comment: While it's true that there are cases where it couldn't work, there certainly are cases where it could.